# Python timedelta result to integer number

Tags: python, python-datetime, timedelta

Sorry I'm beginner, how do you make int the the result of timedelta because it gives the format with "d" and utc, sorry for my bad English

```
          y, m, d = map(int, input('FIRST DATE: ').split(','))
          f_date = date(y, m, d)
          y, m, d = map(int, input('SECOND DATE: ').split(','))
          l_date = date(y, m, d)
          delta = (l_date - f_date:%d)
        i1 = (p * r)
        i2 = (delta / 360)
        i = i1 * i2
        print(i)
```

Comment: please fix your indentations

Comment: What are the variables `p` and `r`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timedelta has three fields, `days`, `seconds`, and `microseconds`.

So `td.days * 86_400 + td.seconds + td.microseconds/1_000_000` gives you the length timedelta `td` in seconds.